# how to use AJAX in page that have normal query data in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I try to run AJAX query in page that have data query via normal laravel controller.
Ajax code is working, but results are not execute , those looping with 'undefined'. Can You anyone help me to solve this.

here is laravel controller for data query from DB

```
public function showUser($id)
{
    $id = request('id');
    $user= Auth::user()->contactNo;
    $padd = adds::where([['ContactNo',$user],['id',request('id')]])->first();
    if(empty($padd)) {
        return view('/welcome');
    }
    else {
        return view('User.ReviewAddUser',compact('padd'));
    }
    
}
```

here is ReviewAddUser.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">

            <h4 class="card-title" id="reduce">{{$padd->Title}}</h4>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Publised on {{$padd->publised_at}} </h6>

            <div class="container col-md-6">
            <div  id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <center>
                    <img style="" class="imgslide" src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$padd->Img1)}}" alt="First slide">
                    </center>
                    </div>
                    @if (!empty($padd->Img2))
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    <center>
                    <img style="" class="imgslide" src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$padd->Img2)}}" alt="Second slide">
                    </center></div>
                    @endif
                    @if (!empty($padd->Img3))
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    <center>
                    <img style="" class="imgslide" src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$padd->Img3)}}" alt="Third slide">
                    </center></div>
                    @endif
                    @if (!empty($padd->Img4))
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    <center>
                    <img style="" class="imgslide" src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$padd->Img4)}}" alt="fourth slide">
                    </center></div>
                    @endif
                    @if (!empty($padd->Img5))
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                    <center>
                    <img style="" class="imgslide" src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$padd->Img5)}}" alt="fifth slide">
                    </center></div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" style="bg-color:black;" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <!--details-->
            @if (!empty($padd->Price))
                <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted ">{{ __('Rs.') }}{{$padd->Price}}</h5>
            @else
                
            @endif
            
            <h6 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">{{ __('Discription') }} : {{$padd->Discription}}</h6>
            <!--<h6 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">{{ __('Video Link') }} : {{$padd->VideoLink}}</h6>-->
            <br>
            <h5 class="card-text mb-2 text-muted">{{ __('Contact Number') }} : <a href="tel:{{$padd->ContactNo1}}">  {{$padd->ContactNo}} </a></h5>

            <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted ">Current Status-{{$padd->Status}}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted ">Current Remark-{{$padd->Remark}}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted ">Current Open Count-{{$padd->AddOpenCount}}</h5>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group" >
                                    <div class="col-md-6 "> 
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="searchKey" id="searchKey" value="{{$padd->RefId}}" >
                                            <button class="btn btn-lg" id="search"><i class="fa fa-search">Show My Offers</i></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                            <th scope="col">UserID</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Offer</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Comment</th>
                                            <th scope="col">PostTime</th>
                                            
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                            <tbody id="addlist" >
                                            
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is  AJAX code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("jquery running1");
 $(document).ready(function($){
    var query = $("#searchKey").val();
    //alert(query);  
        MyOffers();
        function MyOffers(query) {

        $("#addlist").empty();
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ThisAddsOffers',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype:'json',
            data:{SearchKey:query},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                //alert("done");
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                    var Link ="<a target='_blank' href='/OpenAdd4Owner/"+val.id+"' >{{ __('Open') }}</a>";  

                $('#addlist').append('<tr>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.AddID+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.UserID+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.Offer+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.Comment+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.PostTime+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+Link+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('</tr>')

                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                //alert("fail")
                console.log("error");
            })
        
        }
        $("#search").click(function(){ var query = $("#searchKey").val();  MyOffers(query);  });
    });
</script>
```

here is AJAX Code use in ReviewAddUser.blade.php to retrieve data from offer table

```
    public function ThisAddsOffers(Request $request)
{
   if($request->ajax())  {
        $SearchData = $request->get('SearchKey');
        return offers::where('AddID',$SearchData)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    } else { return 'false'; }   
}
```

Comment: Where is your javascript & ajax code?

Comment: sorry for missing, updated code

Comment: what does `data` has in it ?

Comment: data has, that query runs well another place without data from normal query

Answer (score 0):

I think have to issue is the response of function ThisAddsOffers. You can use the function `response()` of Laravel want to result expected.
Example:

```
$result = offers::where('AddID',$SearchData)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();

response()->json(['data' => $result], 200)
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#view-responses

Answer (score 0):

Add in head tag (layout)

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

New JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("jquery running1");
 $(document).ready(function($){
    var query = $("#searchKey").val();
    //alert(query);  
        MyOffers();
        function MyOffers(query) {

        $("#addlist").empty();

             $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ThisAddsOffers',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype:'json',
            data:{SearchKey:query},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                //alert("done");
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                    var Link ="<a target='_blank' href='/OpenAdd4Owner/"+val.id+"' >{{ __('Open') }}</a>";  

                $('#addlist').append('<tr>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.AddID+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.UserID+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.Offer+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.Comment+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.PostTime+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+Link+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('</tr>')

                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                //alert("fail")
                console.log("error");
            })
        
        }
        $("#search").click(function(){ var query = $("#searchKey").val();  MyOffers(query);  });
    });
</script>
```

Test pls. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to attach `query` when you call `MyOffers()` function and parse the JSON. I re-write the controller and AJAX call, please check

```html
$(document).ready(function($){
    var query = $("#searchKey").val();
    //alert(query);  
        MyOffers(query);
        function MyOffers(query) {

        $("#addlist").empty();
            $.ajax({
            url: 'ThisAddsOffers',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype:'json',
            data:{SearchKey:query},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                //alert("done");
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                    var Link ="<a target='_blank' href='/OpenAdd4Owner/"+val.id+"' >{{ __('Open') }}</a>";  

                $('#addlist').append('<tr>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.AddID+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.UserID+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.Offer+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.Comment+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+val.PostTime+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('<td>'+Link+'</td>')
                $('#addlist').append('</tr>')

                });
            })
            .fail(function() {
                //alert("fail")
                console.log("error");
            })
        
        }
        $("#search").click(function(){ var query = $("#searchKey").val();  MyOffers(query);  });
    });
```

And you may update the codes in your controller

```
public function ThisAddsOffers(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())  {
        $SearchData = $request->get('SearchKey');
        if (!empty()) {
            $data = offers::where('AddID', $SearchData)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        } else {
            $data = offers::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
        }

        return response()->json($data);
    } else { 
        return 'false'; 
    }   
}
```